# Generic class of generic class with one argument/parameter

Tags: ios, swift, generics, syntax

I have this syntactical issue with my data structure. What makes it worse is that I can not talk about it in detail. The company I am employed at operates in the public transportation sector and I am under NDA and boss would kill me if I posted anything too specific. I hope you understand!

I have this perfect example though. There are no inconsistencies at all ;)
Well, okay, there are. However I am convinced that most of you out there are smart enough to get what is of importance here.

Basic structure:

```swift
class Propulsion {
    var horsePower: Double
    init(horsePower: Double) {
        self.horsePower = horsePower
    }
    static let pedes = Propulsion(horsePower: 0.2)
}

class Motor: Propulsion {
    var range: Double
    init(range: Double, horsePower: Double) {
        self.range = range
        super.init(horsePower: horsePower)
    }
    static let otto = Motor(range: 1000, horsePower: 100)
    static let electric = Motor(range: 400, horsePower: 200)
}

class Vehicle<P: Propulsion> {
    var propulsion: P
    init(propulsion: P) {
        self.propulsion = propulsion
    }
}

class Bicycle<P: Propulsion>: Vehicle<P> {
    var hasFrontSuspension: Bool
    init(hasFrontSuspension: Bool, propulsion: P) {
        self.hasFrontSuspension = hasFrontSuspension
        super.init(propulsion: propulsion)
    }
}

class Car<P: Propulsion>: Vehicle<P> {
    func rangePerHorsePower() -> Double where P: Motor {
        propulsion.range / propulsion.horsePower
    }
}
```

Now I would like to declare a parking spot for a car. Like so:

```swift
var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpot<Car<Motor>>
```

For the class `ParkingSpot` I have some class like this in mind:

```swift
class ParkingSpot<V: Vehicle<P>> where P: Propulsion {
    var vehicle: Vehicle<P>
    init(vehicle: Vehicle<P>) {
        self.vehicle = vehicle
    }
    func taxForRange() -> Double where P: Motor {
        vehicle.propulsion.range * 50
    }
}
```

From the last bit I get back a bunch of

> Cannot find type 'P' in scope

This one doesn’t work either:

```swift
class ParkingSpot<V: Vehicle<P: Propulsion>>
```

> Expected '>' to complete generic argument list

This implementation works though:

```swift
class ParkingSpot<V: Vehicle<P>, P: Propulsion> {
    var vehicle: Vehicle<P>
    init(vehicle: Vehicle<P>) {
        self.vehicle = vehicle
    }
    func taxForRange() -> Double where P: Motor {
        vehicle.propulsion.range * 50
    }
}
```

However I don’t want to duplicate the `Motor` bit:

```swift
var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpot<Car<Motor>, Motor>
```

How can I accomplish this with just one generic parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the "Protocol oriented" approach:

```
protocol PropulsionP {
    var horsePower: Double { get }
}

protocol MotorP: PropulsionP {
    var range: Double { get }
}

struct MotorS: MotorP {
    var range: Double
    var horsePower: Double

    init(range: Double, horsePower: Double) {
        self.range = range
        self.horsePower = horsePower
    }
}

protocol VehicleP {
    associatedtype P: PropulsionP

    var propulsion: P { get }
}

struct BicycleS<Prop: PropulsionP>: VehicleP {
    let hasFrontSuspension: Bool
    var propulsion: Prop

    init(
        hasFrontSuspension: Bool,
        propulsion: Prop
    ) {
        self.hasFrontSuspension = hasFrontSuspension
        self.propulsion = propulsion
    }
}

struct CarS<Prop: PropulsionP>: VehicleP {
    var propulsion: Prop

    func rangePerHorsePower() -> Double where P: MotorP {
        propulsion.range / propulsion.horsePower
    }
}

struct ParkingSpotS<V: VehicleP> {
    var vehicle: V

    init(vehicle: V) {
        self.vehicle = vehicle
    }

    func taxForRange() -> Double where V.P: MotorP {
        vehicle.propulsion.range * 50
    }
}

var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpotS<CarS<MotorS>>
```

No double `MotorS` bit.
Quod erat demonstrandum.

I used the somewhat unusual naming to emphasize the point.

(needed to make some edit, erronously typed `Motor` where I actually need `MotorP`)

**Update**

I was on the road with my preferred car and tried it out:

```
var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpotS<CarS<MotorS>> = .init(
    vehicle: .init(
        propulsion: .init(
            range: 760,
            horsePower: 240
        )
    )
)

print(carParkingSpot.taxForRange())
```

```
38000.0
```

Alternatively you can use this initialiser:

```
var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpotS = .init(
    vehicle: CarS(
        propulsion: MotorS(
            range: 760,
            horsePower: 240
        )
    )
)
```

**Update**

Now suppose you are utilising a third party library which already provides a nice implementation of a motor.

What you need to do is to implement an *extension* for *their* given class or struct `TheirMotor` which conforms to *your* protocol `MotorP`:

```
import FancyMotors

extension TheirMotor: MotorP {
    let range: Double {
        // calculate `range` in terms of the 
        // given API of `TheirMotor`:
        ...
        return range
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like below:

```
var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpotS = .init(
    vehicle: CarS(
        propulsion: TheirMotor( 
            distance: 760,
            power: 240
        )
    )
)
```

Note, that you use `TheirMotor` and need to use the appropriate initialiser to create it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly I can’t change Propulsion and Motor. These are embedded in a framework we use. That’s why I wanted to have a class with generic Vehicle and generic Propulsion.

Comment: @JackS You can _extend_ any existing class or struct from third party libraries without the need to modify their sources, so that they conform to _your_ protocol. Just define an extension which conforms to your protocol:  `extension TheirMotor: MotorP { <add conformance> }`. Note that `TheirMotor` can be a class _or_ a struct. In essence, this kind of extension is like an _adapter_ which looks like a `MotorP`, but internally is a `TheirMotor`.

Comment: @JackS I added an update to illustrate the usage of a third party motor implementation, without changing any sources of the third party library.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
class ParkingSpot<V: Vehicle<Propulsion>>
{
    var vehicle: V
    init(vehicle: V)
    {
        self.vehicle = vehicle
    }

    func taxForEngineeNoise() -> Double
    {
        switch vehicle.propulsion
        {
        case is Motor:
            return vehicle.propulsion.horsePower * 50

        default:
            ...
        }
    }

    func taxForRange() -> Double
    {
        if let motor = vehicle.propulsion as? Motor
        {
            return motor.range * 50
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, perhaps hide the duplication where you can?

```
typealias ParkingSpotX = ParkingSpot<Car<Motor>, Motor>

var parkingSpot: ParkingSpotX
```

Comment: With this we lose the specific type of Propulsion: `var carParkingSpot: ParkingSpot<Car<Motor>>` gives `'ParkingSpot' requires that 'Car<Motor>' inherit from 'Vehicle<Propulsion>'`

Comment: I also made a mistake taxing engine noise when actually it should be the `Motor` specific range: `func taxForRange() -> Double where P: Motor { vehicle.propulsion.range * 50 }`. With this your solution doesn’t work: `Value of type 'Propulsion' has no member 'range'`.

Comment: @JackS can easily get this to work too, see extended answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I’d personally prefer a clean solution where both types are generic. I am sure your solution will help someone stumbling upon this.

Comment: @JackS I understand your quest to make things generic and clean. Often it's good to be pragmatic. In this case you might be able to ask yourself, of course I don't know the full context, how many vehicle propulsion combinations actually exist and what generics add. Good luck, I do hope you get things as you prefer.